# ¿Cómo sacar la mediana en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

Un gusto de antemano. (Hubo una confusión en la pregunta)

Estoy intentando sacar las medidas de tendencia central (Moda, Media y Mediana) de un muestreo de 50 alumnos, la media, mediana y la moda son de la edad de mi tabla alumnos.

La moda y la media ya las pude sacar, adjunto evidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los datos de mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo idea de como formular la consulta de la mediana, estoy empezando a usar sql server.

Comment: Bienvenido Griggle a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Cuidado, `avg()` es el promedio o media, no la mediana

Comment: Entonces me esta diciendo que saque la media y no la mediana (?) :=(

Comment: Estas confundido, lo q estas obteniendo es la media, lo q te falta es la mediana

Comment: Necesitamos que compartas la estructura de tus tablas en formato de código y datos de prueba. También la versión de SQL que estás usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunos detalles en tus cálculos que pueden ser ineficientes o regresar errores incorrectos.

Por ejemplo, para calcular la moda, puedes simplemente limitar el número de filas regresadas. Eso hace la consulta mucho más sencilla y solo tienes que leer la tabla una vez.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    edad AS moda
FROM dbo.Alumnos
GROUP BY edad
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Para la media (el promedio), puedes tener un resultado incorrecto ya que regresas un entero que puede ser inexacto. Para obtener decimales, hay que cambiar el tipo de dato.

```
SELECT AVG( CAST( edad AS decimal(10,2))) AS media
FROM dbo.alumnos;
```

Por último, para obtener la mediana, podemos utilizar una función poco conocida de SQL Server que fue introducida en la versión 2012 (si mal no recuerdo).

```
SELECT TOP 1
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edad) OVER() AS mediana
FROM alumnos;
```

El 0.5 indica el porcentaje de filas que habrá hacia arriba (50%). Por lo tanto, estaremos sacando el valor que está justo al centro del conjunto de datos. Tenemos que indicar sobre cual conjunto queremos sacar el valor, eso lo indica `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edad)`. Por último tenemos la clausula `OVER()` que nos puede ayudar a generar particiones, por ejemplo si quisieras sacar la moda por grupos y no de todos los alumnos.

Si quisieras tener todos en un solo resultado, los puedes poner en columnas.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1
           PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edad) OVER() AS mediana
    FROM alumnos) mdn
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 
        edad AS moda
    FROM Alumnos
    GROUP BY edad
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) mo
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG( CAST( edad AS decimal(10,2))) AS media
    FROM alumnos) me;
```

Por cierto, también hay funciones para obtener la varianza y la desviación estándar.